# What is the corret use of use case diagram

Tags: uml, state-diagram

What is corret use of this model .. the 1. or 2. ? ... or should have 1. extends instead of include ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the UC in #1 should read "item selection" and not section.

Both of your designs are wrong in the one or other way. "item selection" is not a use case. It does not deliver any value to Actor (at least none I could imagine). So you are trying to put a CRUD into a use case. Re-think on what the actual value is the Actor expects.

Now for include/extend: Avoid them where possible. Once you start decomposing use cases you got it wrong and if your use case diagrams resemble spider webs your design is simply broken. Use cases are synthesized, not analyzed. While the first tried to build a complete picture, the latter is something you need in code design to cut it into manageable pieces.